# Sort keys in dictionary based of list of keys

Tags: python-3.x

I want to come up sorted list of only those keys which are mentioned in list .

```
def main():
    D ={'acct_number':10202,'acct_name':'abc','v1_rev':200,'v2_rev':210,'v4_rev':2,'v5_rev':200,'v6_rev':210,'v7_rev':60000000,'v3_rev':2000}
    result = ['v1_rev', 'v5_rev', 'v2_rev', 'v6_rev']
    keys2 = sorted(D, key=D.get(lambda x: (for x in result)))  # sorting keys in value ascending  order
    print(keys2)




if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

```
    keys2 = sorted(D, key=D.get(lambda x: (for x in result)))  # sorting keys in value ascending  order
                                           ^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `sorted(k for k in D if k in result)`

Comment: That was quick . Thanks @StevenRumbalski